# Sorting Directories and Files

Tags: find, sort

I want to use `find` and sort the response. I assumed that a simple pipe `find ... | sort` would do it, but the sorting behaviour is weird. For simplicity a simple text file:

```
asdf/2/22
asdf/2/01
asdf/20/0
asdf/20/1
```

My expected result would be

```
asdf/2/01
asdf/2/22
asdf/20/0
asdf/20/1
```

or

```
asdf/20/0
asdf/20/1
asdf/2/01
asdf/2/22
```

It doesn't matter as I only want the directories to appear in groups.

Here are my attempts:

```
[root@linux6 ~]# cat sort_test | sort
asdf/20/0
asdf/2/01
asdf/20/1
asdf/2/22
[root@linux6 ~]# cat sort_test | sort -d
asdf/20/0
asdf/2/01
asdf/20/1
asdf/2/22
[root@linux6 ~]# cat sort_test | tr "/" "X" | sort
asdfX20X0
asdfX20X1
asdfX2X01
asdfX2X22
[root@linux6 ~]# cat sort_test | tr "/" "_" | sort
asdf_20_0
asdf_2_01
asdf_20_1
asdf_2_22
[root@linux6 ~]#
```

Note that it only works with "X". Any non-alphanumeric character seems to break the output. I also tried the `-s`, `-t '/'` options with no change in the output.

`sort` seems to remove the non-alphanumeric characters first and then sort the line even though I didn't mention `-d`. There is no `alias` for sort.

```
[root@linux6 ~]# which sort
/usr/bin/sort
[root@linux6 ~]# uname -a
Linux i-epg-appl1 3.10.0-229.14.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Sep 15 15:05:51 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[root@linux6 ~]# sort --version
sort (GNU coreutils) 8.22
```

Comment: Switch collation to `C` e.g. `LC_COLLATE=C sort infile`

Comment: Or also try LANG to be set to C (or en_US.UTF-8)

Comment: @don_crissti You are right, it wasn't set on my machine. If you want some reputation make that an answer :). BTW, `LANG` is set and apparently didn't help here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So just to wrap up this question the answer is to set `LC_COLLATE` as @don_crissti mentioned in the comment:

```
$ LC_COLLATE=C sort infile
```

Answer (score 2):

In first instance, the `/` will be ignored in your locale for sorting (you'll notice that all but the last weight in the collection specification for `/` is `IGNORE` on a GNU system for most locales (`<U002F> IGNORE;IGNORE;IGNORE;<U002F> # 45 /` in `/usr/share/i18n/locales/iso14651_t1_common` on my Debian system)), so sorting `asdf/20/0` against `asdf/2/01` is like sorting `asdf200` against `asdf201`, as if you had used `-d`.

You could change the locale to C where the sorting is only based on byte value (and `/` happens to sort *before* digits) so `asdf/2/01` would sort before `asdf/20/0` as `/` sorts before `0`, but you'd still have problem with `asdf/2` against `asdf/10` for instance.

Here, you could use the GNU-specific `-g`/`--general-numeric-sort` option, or you could do:

```
sort -nt/ -k1,1 -k2,2 -k3,3 -k4,4 -k5,5 -k6,6 -k7,7 -k8,8 -k9,9
```

To consider each directory component as a number (that will sort 2_ before

With `zsh`, you can do:

```
printf '%s\n' **/*(Dn)
```

to do a recursive glob numerically sorted.